# how to integrate ckeditor image browser in jsp

Tags: jsp, ckeditor

I am having problem with `ckeditor browse image`

```
filebrowserImageBrowseUrl: '../ckfinder/ckfinder/ckfinder.html?type=Images',
            filebrowserImageUploadUrl: 
'/ckfinder/core/connector/php/connector.php?command=QuickUpload&type=Images'
```

What do these two lines indicate/require?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly do you have the CkFinder addon? This is a paid addon that you can purchase from CkEditor for uploading files and browsing files.

If you do not have one, you must create your own.

The filebrowserImageBrowseUrl points to your browser.  When a user browses, this window pops out _(or some other feature, this is controlled by the configuration setting [filebrowserWindowFeatures](https://docs.ckeditor.com/ckeditor4/latest/api/CKEDITOR_config.html#cfg-filebrowserWindowFeatures))

THere is also the two configurations [filebrowserWindowWidth](https://docs.ckeditor.com/ckeditor4/latest/api/CKEDITOR_config.html#cfg-filebrowserWindowWidth) and [filebrowserWindowHeight](https://docs.ckeditor.com/ckeditor4/latest/api/CKEDITOR_config.html#cfg-filebrowserWindowHeight).

The filebrowserImageUploadUrl points to either the CKFinder URL if you have purchased it, or if not, a self created upload tool for your application.

Mine for example is as follows:

```
config.filebrowserImageUploadUrl = "../upload?type=image";
config.imageUploadUrl = "../upload?type=image";
config.uploadUrl = "../upload?type=file";
```

The filebrowserImageBrowseUrl can either point to the CKFinder or again a customer browser created by yourself. Here is the set up for my browser

```
var browseUrl = "../../****messenger/filelibrary/getimages/" + bottom_left_nav_selected;
var url = "../components/browser/browser.html?listType=images&listUrl=" + encodeURIComponent(browseUrl);
if (config.baseHref) {
    url += "&baseHref=" + encodeURIComponent(config.baseHref);
}
config.filebrowserImageBrowseUrl = url;
```

For more information on integrating CkFinder, please refer to this [page](https://docs.ckeditor.com/ckeditor4/latest/guide/dev_ckfinder_integration.html)

for more information on creating your own file upload and browse system that works with CkEditor, please refer to this [page](https://docs.ckeditor.com/ckeditor4/latest/guide/dev_ckfinder_integration.html)